# Not able to copy Korean characters from PDF file using Acrobat Reader

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat, encoding, unicode

I decided to study Korean and I found a book that I want to copy some vocabulary from, the problem is when I paste the copied text, it turns into gibberish characters. Any idea how to solve this? I also tried using other PDF viewers but the outcome is still the same.

This is the word I want to copy for example,

[image]

This is the output I am getting:

[image]

I read somewhere that I need ot install the font used in this PDF file, and I found that it uses this font

[image]

I downloaded the font from https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/nanumgothic and installed it, but still, the outcome remains the same. I'm currently at a lost.